# Safari 5.1 unloading tabs from memory

Tags: safari, osx-lion

Well, it seems Safari 5.1 at least on Lion which is what I'm using now decides to unload tabs from memory as it deems it necessary.

The big issue with this is sites that display ajax alerts or ones that have chats as for example GMail. I was having 2 conversations on Google Talk right in the GMail website and while I was on another tab I noticed the title blinking indicating new messages in my conversations, as soon as I clicked the tab Safari decided to completely reload the page, losing all those conversations (I don't keep logs of those).

It goes without saying that this behavior breaks modern web apps and seems unnecessary on a desktop computer. I understand the necessity of this on iOS devices due to ram constrains though.

Is there any way to disable this "feature", I couldn't find a way to do so. It's that or switching to Chrome or Firefox, but I like Safari.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably should file a bug about this, telling them about the data loss it causes. https://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a temporary work around. Pages on my site — petersonguides.com — periodically reload the tab in Safari 5.1. Ordinarily this wouldn't be a big issue, but I have a video that plays in a FancyZoom box and it can't get all the way through without the tab being refreshed.

I tested with Chrome and it doesn't cause the same tab reload behavior, so I'm sure it's a Safari 5.1 problem.

I have JavaScript and PHP on the home page and I thought there might be a conflict, so I started pulling things off and retesting with the video. The last thing I checked was removing the Google Analytics script. That fixed the problem.

I tried bumping up the Database Storage amount - per the previous answer - but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: Did a bit more diggin and found [this](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=7b4aea6acab6efd7&hl=en) on the Google Analytics forum. A cookie left behind by GA Site Overlay can cause the refresh problem. To remove it, go to Safari:Preferences:Privacy and click on Details. I couldn't find the cookie with "GASO" as indicated in the forum thread, but I found one for my site—petersonguides.com—and deleted it. This solved the refresh problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble with Pandora (Flash) not advancing songs in a background tab. As a quick-and-dirty test, I went to **Preferences > Advanced > Database storage** and popped it up from 5MB to 500MB. Flash is still very unstable, but now songs are advancing in the background. I don't know if this will work for you but you might give it a try.

Safari 5.1 | OS X 10.6.8

Answer (score 0):

The reloading of tabs in the background is a feature of Safari 5.1 on Lion. There is currently no easy way to get around this. The only way possible at the moment involves disabling the multi-process window feature:

1. Enable Safari's Debug menu by typing in Terminal.app, restarting Safari afterwards:

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1
   ```
2. From the new Debug menu in Safari, select *Use Multi-process Windows* to remove the tick before it and deactivate this feature.

While this prevents tab reloading in the background it will disable extensions and gestures in Safari. But it can be easily activated again via the Debug menu.